# Area between a parabola and its normal at a point $(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Consider the parabola $P$ given by $y=ax^2$ for $a>0$.  At each point $(x_0, y_0)$ on $P$, construct the normal line through $(x_0, y_0)$ perpendicular tot he tangent line, and consider the area of the sector of $P$ cut off by this line.  Find the minimal area of this sector.  What are the slopes of the normal lines that minimize this area?

I started off by constructing the normal line formula:
$$y=f(x_0)+\frac{-1}{f'(x_0)}(x - x_0)$$
$$y=a{x_0}^2-\frac{1}{2ax_0}(x-x_0)$$
$$g(x) =y=\left(a{x_0}^2+\frac{1}{2a}\right)-\frac{x}{2ax_0}$$

I can then find the area using:

$$A=\int_b^{x_0}g(x)-P\space dx$$ 
$$=\int_b^{x_0}\left(a{x_0}^2+\frac{1}{2a}\right)-\frac{x}{2ax_0}-ax^2dx$$
where $x_0 > 0$ and $b$ is the intersection of $g(x)$ and $P$ but finding the point of intersection is quite ugly:
$$b=\frac{\frac{-1}{2ax_0} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4a^2{x_0}^2} - 4a\bigg(-a{x_0}^2-\frac{1}{2a}\bigg)}}{2a} \text{ where } b\ne x_0$$

Is there a better way of setting this up??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P: y = ax^2
\end{align}
and let $L$ be the equation of line:
\begin{align}
L: l = y(x_0)+\frac{-1}{y'(x_0)}(x-x_0) = ax_0^2 - \frac{1}{2ax_0}(x-x_0)
\end{align}
This is correct
so what you want to know is the area between line $L$ and a parabola $P$ right?
if you let $x_1$ be other intersection (it was $b$ in your original post)
\begin{align}
A = \int_{x_1}^{x_0} L-P = -\int_{x_1}^{x_0}\left(ax^2+\frac{1}{2ax_0}(x-x_0)-ax_0^2\right)dx
\end{align}
but then, if you think about it, $L-P =0$ when $x = x_0$ and $x=x_1$ right?
so A can be transformed to the much simpler equation
\begin{align}
A = -a\int_{x_1}^{x_0} \left[(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\right]dx = a\frac{1}{6}\left( x_0-x_1\right)^3
\end{align}
(you can work this out right?)  now what is $x_1$
\begin{align}
L-P &= a\left\{ x^2 + \frac{1}{2a^2x_0}(x-x_0)-x_0^2\right\} = a\left\{ (x+x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{1}{2a^2x_0}(x-x_0) \right\}\\
&=a(x-x_0)\left[x+\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2a^2x_0}\right)\right] 
\end{align}
so,
\begin{align}
x_1 = -\left( x_0+\frac{1}{2a^2x_0} \right)
\end{align}
therefore the answer is,
\begin{align}
A(x_0) &= -a\int_{x_1}^{x_0} \left[(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\right]dx = a\frac{1}{6}\left( x_0-x_1\right)^3 \\
&=a\frac{1}{6}\left(2x_0+\frac{1}{2a^2x_0}\right)^3
\end{align}
if you take a derivative of $A$ with respect to $x_0$ then:
\begin{align}
A' = a\frac{1}{3}\left(2x_0+\frac{1}{2a^2x_0}\right)^2\left(2-\frac{1}{2a^2x_0^2} \right)
\end{align}
solve for $A' = 0$
\begin{align}
A' &= a\frac{1}{3}\left(2x_0+\frac{1}{2a^2x_0}\right)^2\left(2-\frac{1}{2a^2x_0^2} \right) = 0\\
2 &= \frac{1}{2a^2x_0^2}\\
4a^2 &= \frac{1}{x_0^2} \\
x_0 &= \pm \frac{1}{2a}
\end{align}
so after all, slope of a normal that minimises the area is $\pm 1$
hope it helps.

Comment: It is kind of interesting that slope that minimises the area is always $\pm 1$ regardless of the value a

Answer (score 0):

i will set $a = 1$ and work with $y = x^2.$  pick a point $P = (t, t^2), t > 0.$  the normal at $P$ is given by $$2t(y-t^2) + (x-t) = 0$$ look for a point $Q = (s, s^2), s < 0.$   solving $2t(s^2-t^2) + (s-t) = 0$ give $s = -t - 1/(2t).$ the area of the sector is 
$$f(t) = \int_s^t \left( t^2 - \frac{x-t}{2t} - x^2 \right)\, dx = (t^2+\frac{1}{2})(t-s) - 
\frac{t^2-s^2}{4t} -\frac{t^3-s^3}{3}$$

you can optimize $f(t), 0 < t < \infty.$